# ASP.NET MVC project with Web API: Simple authorization/authentication is a utopia?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, role-base-authorization

I want to build a rather simple , medium size application.

BUT it has to be strong in 2 areas:

1) Authentication/Authorization with minimum roles implementation (users will be either normal or pro)

2) User Data encryption.

I was happy to see v2 of Identity coming out and thought that now is the time to start learning.

Unfortunately all the resources follow the logic of the pre build logic from Visual Studio templates. After that if you truly want to master Identity you simply can't...If you don't like EF for persistence you are unlucky...

I am certainly not capable of managing a custom rewrite for a security framework.

Its frustrating that i just cant find a simple way to just be able to put simple authentication/authorization in my MVC/Web Api project.

So frustrating that i start thinking of building this to Laravel...

So i started thinking what i should do?

I read this suggestion of forms authentication: [Custom Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/G54G220114-Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html)

Also i have read this very good [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)

But i need to decide on a way safe for my users and i just think that MS identity although in v2 is just a spoiled child that wants everything....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity 2.0 does a LOT of things for you.  It's not well documented by Microsoft (at the moment) and few tutorials exists which makes it kind of frustrating at times.

However, Identity 2.0 gets a lot of things right and it does it for you.  2-factor auth?  Done.  Roles, Claims, Logins, and security logic?  Taken care of.  I've been reading these [articles](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/04/20/ASPNET-MVC-and-Identity-20-Understanding-the-Basics.aspx) which has been somewhat helpful.  However, I do use EF as my persistence framework but might switch to either a DocumentDB or a GraphDB but I still want to use Identity 2.0.

Anyways, rolling your own isn't bad (I've done so prior to Identity 1.0 back when ASP.NET membership was a total pain) but you can offload all that work by simply spending a little bit of time and reading up on how to use it.